# How to convert int64 to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that has a column of type int64 but this columns represets date, e.g. 20180501. I'd like to convert this column to datetime and I'm having the following code but it returns an error message

```
 df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['old_date'].astype('str'), format = '%y%m%d')
```

I'm getting the following error message

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0501
```

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 10):

You need a capital `Y`. See [Python's strftime directives](http://strftime.org/) for a complete reference.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'old_date': [20180501, 20181230, 20181001]})

df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['old_date'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')

print(df)

   old_date   new_date
0  20180501 2018-05-01
1  20181230 2018-12-30
2  20181001 2018-10-01
```

Comment: Unfortunately with or without '.astype(str)' it has not effect (silent fail)... when trying to convert from '%Y-%m-%d' to '%d/%m/%Y'.

Comment: I get error 

ValueError: unconverted data remains: 1

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the problem arises due to a format error at some places in the dataframe.

You could try setting the parameter errors="coerce" to avoid converting those entries and setting them to NaT.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html